# Converting ArcMap layout to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, mxd

How can I export the layout view elements of an ArcGIS 10.6 project for use in the QGIS 3.4.2 print layout? Apart from the shapefiles that accompany the project, I would like to be able to make the same map layout that I use in ArcGIS available for QGIS. At the moment it's just an .mxd file.

I've seen some plugins like SLYR (https://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/slyr/) and Mxd2Qgs (https://github.com/oware/Mxd2Qgs) but don't know if these will accomplish what I need.

Would vector or image formats work, and can these layout paths help me?

[image]

Comment: "Best" questions are problematic here in GIS SE, since they are more discussion-oriented and opinion-based than our Focused question/Best answer model generally supports. This would not be inappropriate for [Chat], but our chat feature is *underutilized*, so you might get a better discussion in a different forum.

Comment: I've heard that mxd2qgs might not be compatible with QGIS 3, but you will have to try it for your project and find out. My guess is that the incompatible parts will be anything in pyqgis, and a few expression builder expressions, but basic styles should transfer okay.

Comment: On the other hand, North Road's “Convert MXD to QGS” algorithm claims to do exactly what you want. If you have a spare 1000 euros lying around, try it out and let us know (at that price not many people have actually tried this tool, but a lot of us are waiting for someone with deeper pockets to contribute to making it open source). (Also, at that price if it doesn't do what you want you can absolutely demand your money back).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Upon editing the python script that comes with the Mxd2Qgs tool, it worked to convert an .mxd to .xml. Now it's a question of opening that .xml in QGIS! Any suggestions?

Comment: See what changes were made: https://github.com/oware/Mxd2Qgs/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the North Road page about [SLYR](https://north-road.com/slyr/) to see if these tool fill your need (it look like they will).

Note that :

> the specifications and file parsing library will initially be closed
>   source and available to SLYR license holders only

So you will have to buy it or wait for 6 month after enough other people buy it...

These tool are a more advanced version of the freely available SLYR plugin (https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr) that "only" convert the ESRI .style file to QGIS compatible style.

Regarding the Mxd2Qgs plugin the description seem to state that its for exporting layer only but why not test it to see if it fill your need ?

Comment: It looks like the basic SLYR tool will be freely available in June 2020. But, the “Convert MXD to QGS” algorithm is only at 0% of its funding goal so it will probably be a long wait.

Comment: Thanks both - SLYR looks great and I may be able to re-visit in the future. @J.R see my above comment.